# Permutations of a set that keep at least one integer fixed

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

what is the number of permutations of a set say {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} that keep at least one integer fixed ?

Comment: What is the number of permutations that keep the 1 fixed? Answer this and you will be able to answer your question.

Comment: n! - # of perms that keep none fixed (latter is called a derangement, closed form formulae are available)

Comment: Yes, listen to Djaian, but possibly instead think of those that leave 5 fixed. Doesn't really matter however.

Comment: I think it should say "permutations *on* a set" rather than *of* a set. You could say permutations of a sequence though.

Comment: @Djaian: this is not enough by itself. @muad: permutations of a set is fine.

Comment: @Qiaochu : you are right. I got tricked like a real beginner here. My bad, I should have thought a little bit before commenting :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is equal to $n!$ minus the number of permutations which keep no elements fixed.  These are known as [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and you can find all the relevant formulas at the Wikipedia article.  You can count them, for example, using inclusion-exclusion.

If you just want the number of derangements of an $n$-element set, then a nice way to compute it is to round $\frac{n!}{e}$ to the nearest integer.  For example, when $n = 5$ we want to round $\frac{120}{e} \approx 44.1$, so there are $44$ derangements, hence $120 - 44 = 76$ permutations which fix at least one element.

Comment: +1,nice explanation, also this link gives a nice idea for computing derangement :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Derangements